# Filter object data and split it into several objects in react native

Tags: node.js, json, react-native, object, fetch-api

I want manipulate JSON input data and output it in different objects,
for example the data below will be as input:

```
   const data= [{"code": "500", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "PROGRAMMING"},
    {"code": "1303", "dayTime": "On FRI 9AM - 11AM", "group_id": "01202110666", "location": "A0715", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:37:11.000Z","subjectName": "DISTRIBUTED SYSTEM"},
    {"code": "503", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "CLIENT SERVER"}]
```

As you can see in the object I have three subjects names and each one has unique code. I want to take every code data into new object, in other words, based on the data I should have three objects each one have the subject data related to the code.
the expected outcome should look something like this:

```
  const data1=  [{"code": "500", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "PROGRAMMING"}]

 const data2=   [{"code": "1303", "dayTime": "On FRI 9AM - 11AM", "group_id": "01202110666", "location": "A0715", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:37:11.000Z","subjectName": "DISTRIBUTED SYSTEM"}]

   const data3=   [{"code": "503", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "CLIENT SERVER"}]
```

I used `forEach` to assign the data to new object, but how to assign it based on **"code" item** and make it like loop every data with different code assign it to new object

thanks in advance

Comment: 1. better than words, you should post the expected output based on data (the expected json)
2. stating you are using fetchApi or react is irrelevant you can just manipulate json input

Comment: But output is just three array, which is what you had with your push? do you mean ```{500: {code: 500, dayTime,...}, 1303: {code: 1303, ...}, 503:{...}}``` where output is an **object** whose **keys** are the code and where values the object associated to the code ?

Comment: @grodzi no, the output is three objects inside array, but the output i want three objects so i can store each on inside variable, however if the way you mentioned is possible to achieve what I am looking for than you can give me an example

Comment: It looks trivial so maybe I have yet not understood. Can't you just do ```const a = codes[0]; const b=codes[1]; const c=codes[2]``` given codes is your input array? (shorthand being ```const [a,b,c] = codes```)

Comment: @grodzi the input will be one json data, the output will be three separated based on the unique code. so input will be on variable holding data after filtering i will get three variable. i have updated the question check it out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
const data= [{"code": "500", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "PROGRAMMING"},
    {"code": "1303", "dayTime": "On FRI 9AM - 11AM", "group_id": "01202110666", "location": "A0715", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:37:11.000Z","subjectName": "DISTRIBUTED SYSTEM"},
    {"code": "503", "dayTime": "On MON 11AM - 13PM", "group_id":"012021106667", "location": "A0716", "scanningTime": "2021-01-22T06:10:40.000Z", "subjectName": "CLIENT SERVER"}]
const code500 = []
const code1303 = []
const code503 = []

data.forEach((arr) => {
  switch (arr.code) {
    case '500': {
      code500.push(arr)
      break
    }
    case '1303': {
      code1303.push(arr)
      break
    }
    case '503': {
      code503.push(arr)
      break
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unrecognised code '${arr.code}'`)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: that is perfect, but  when I have two data with same code will print them together in same array same like in one `const data1` or separate, if no how I can achieve that

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!